# Force sort command to ignore folder names

Tags: bash, sorting, find

I ran the following from a base folder ./

```
find . -name *.xvi.txt | sort
```

Which returns the following sort order:

```
./LT/filename.2004167.xvi.txt
./LT/filename.2004247.xvi.txt
./pred/2004186/filename.2004186.xvi.txt
./pred/2004202/filename.2004202.xvi.txt
./pred/2004222/filename.2004222.xvi.txt
```

As you can see, the filenames follow a regular structure, but the files themselves might be located in different parts of the directory structure. Is there a way of ignoring the folder names and/or directory structure so that the sort returns a list of folders/filenames based ONLY on the file names themselves? Like so:

```
./LT/filename.2004167.xvi.txt
./pred/2004186/filename.2004186.xvi.txt
./pred/2004202/filename.2004202.xvi.txt
./pred/2004222/filename.2004222.xvi.txt
./LT/filename.2004247.xvi.txt
```

I've tried a few different switches under the find and sort commands, but no luck. I could always copy everything out to a single folder and sort from there, but there are several hundred files, and I'm hoping that a more elegant option exists.

Thanks! Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you put quotes around the argument to `-name`. Otherwise this will stop working if you ever have any files with the extension `xvi.txt` in the base directory.

Comment: I didn't realize I had picked up a bad habit. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -name *.xvi.txt | sort -t'.' -k3 -n
```

will sort it as you want. the only problem is if filename or directory name will include additinal dots.

To avoid it you can use :

```
find . -name *.xvi.txt | sed 's/[0-9]\+.xvi.txt$/\\&/' | sort -t'\' -k2 | sed 's/\\//'
```

Comment: This was the only answer that worked straight out of the box for me. 

So, if I'm reading this right, the sort command is dividing up the list based on a selected deliminator (-t'.'). It then uses the info in the third column (-k3), which is the numerical value (e.g., 2004186) stripped out, and then sorts numerically (-n)? I do see what you mean about extra periods though.

Comment: @Prophet60091 you're right. The way with `sed` shouldn't have such problem.

Answer (score 6):

If your `find` has `-printf` you can print both the base filename and the full filename. Sort by the first field, then strip it off.

```
find . -name '*.xvi.txt' -printf '%f %p\n' | sort -k1,1 | cut -f 2- -d ' '
```

I have chosen a space as a delimiter. If your filenames include spaces, you should choose another delimiter which is a character that's not in your filenames. If any filenames include newlines, you'll have to modify this because it won't work.

Note that the glob in the `find` command should be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

If your `find` doesn't have `printf`, you could use `awk` to accomplish the same thing:

```
find . -name *.xvi.txt | awk -F / '{ print $NF, $0 }' | sort | sed 's/.* //'
```

The same caveats about spaces that Dennis Williamson mentioned apply here. And for variety, I'm using `sed` to strip off the sort field, instead of `cut`.